# is it haram to play Among Us

Tags: halal-haram, game, lying

I play a game called among us but when you get imposter you have to lie in the game like accusing someone as the imposter and lying is haram right so I just wanted to know if it is halal to play that game.

Comment: @goldPseudo ok I will use comment from now on

Answer (score 0):

It’s halal to play Among Us as it’s just a video game that has no great impact on your life and that doesn’t violate Islamic rules.

Answer (score 0):

No i do not think so, as there are no elements of Shirk, Kufr, Zinah or any other major sin.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends if you avoid lying in the game IMO it becomes makruh but when you start to lie in the game this is haram. Prophet Muhammed (ﷺ) said: “I guarantee a home in the suburbs of Paradise for one who leaves off argument even when he is right, & a home in the middle of Paradise for one who abandons lying even in jest, & a home in the highest part of Paradise for one who excels in character

Comment: so is it haram to play the game with lying and halal to play it without lying